# Dependent Things PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have this two files:

new_aircraft.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Insert Aircraft</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//Ajax Script
function require(){
    try{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(err1){
        try{
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(err2){
            try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(err3){
            req = false;
            }
        }
    }
return req;
}


var request = require();

function callAjax(){
var ramdom = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
valor = document.getElementById("numberclasses").value;
var url="classes.php?Value="+valor+"&r="+ramdom;
request.open("GET",url,true);
request.onreadystatechange = answerAjax;
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(null);
}

function answerAjax(){

    if(request.readyState==4){
        if(request.status==200){
        //alert(request.responseText);
        document.getElementById("classes").innerHTML=request.responseText;
        }else{
        alert("ha ocurrido un error"+request.statusText);
        }
    }
}

</script>
<?

$boton = $_POST['enviar'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$pax = $_POST['pax'];
$ICAO = $_POST['ICAO'];

if($boton == 'Insertar')
{
    include('./db.inc.php');

    $ICAO = strtoupper($ICAO);      
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO flota(ICAO, nombre, precio, capacidad) VALUES('$ICAO', '$nombre', '$precio', '$pax')") or die('<h4 style="color: red;">Ha habido un problema con la insercion.</h4>');

    mysql_close();

    echo '<h3 style="color: green;">Aeronave adquirida correctamente.<h3/>';
}
else
{
    ?>
    <form action="insertar-modelo.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
    <tr><td class=Forms>ICAO: </td><td><input type="text" value="" name="ICAO" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Name: </td><td><input type="text" value="Airbus A320" name="nombre" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Price: </td><td><input maxlength="9" value="1000000" type="text" name="precio" /> €</td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Number Classes: </td></td><td><select name="numberclasses" id="numberclasses" onchange="callAjax()">
        <option>Select Number of Classes</option>
        <?php
        echo'<option value="1">One</option>';
        ?>
    </select></td></tr>


<tr><td id="classes" ></td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Capacidad: </td><td><input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /> pasajeros</td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Insertar"/>
    </form>
    <?
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

classes.php

```
 <?php
$value = $_GET['Value'];

if($value == 1){


    ?>


<thead>
    <td class=Forms>First Class: </td><td><input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /></td>
</thead>


<?php
}

?>
```

And the result when I "Select Number of Classes" 1 is http://i48.tinypic.com/erbfnn.png (It is an image, please see it).

The First Class part isn´t on the correct order. It should below Number Classes but It is the first. And First Class part doesn´t respect the other parts width.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I like your title.. dependent things.. I like things.. very much.. I hope things likes me to :|

Answer (score 1):

The children of `<table>` must only be `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>`; you can also have `<tr>`, it will automatically wrap them in `<tbody>`.

So change:

`<div id="classes"></div>`

to:

`<tr><td id="classes"></td></tr>`

You also have one `<form>` but to `</form>` elements, you need to match them and nest properly. You can't start a form outside the table end and it inside, so get rid of the extra `</form>` inside the table.

Comment: `So change <div id="classes"></div> to:` ... ?

Comment: I always blame SO too if I mess up things :P

Comment: @dbf I did the usual thing of indenting code 4 spaces, but it decided I was entering literal HTML rather than code, maybe because of the inline code I'd put on earlier lines.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the files:

new_aircraft.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Insert Aircraft</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//Ajax Script
function require(){
    try{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(err1){
        try{
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(err2){
            try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(err3){
            req = false;
            }
        }
    }
return req;
}


var request = require();

function callAjax(){
var ramdom = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
valor = document.getElementById("numberclasses").value;
var url="classes.php?Value="+valor+"&r="+ramdom;
request.open("GET",url,true);
request.onreadystatechange = answerAjax;
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(null);
}

function answerAjax(){

    if(request.readyState==4){
        if(request.status==200){
        //alert(request.responseText);
        document.getElementById("classes").innerHTML=request.responseText;
        }else{
        alert("ha ocurrido un error"+request.statusText);
        }
    }
}

</script>
<?

$boton = $_POST['enviar'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$pax = $_POST['pax'];
$ICAO = $_POST['ICAO'];

if($boton == 'Insertar')
{
    include('./db.inc.php');

    $ICAO = strtoupper($ICAO);      
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO flota(ICAO, nombre, precio, capacidad) VALUES('$ICAO', '$nombre', '$precio', '$pax')") or die('<h4 style="color: red;">Ha habido un problema con la insercion.</h4>');

    mysql_close();

    echo '<h3 style="color: green;">Aeronave adquirida correctamente.<h3/>';
}
else
{
    ?>
    <form action="insertar-modelo.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
    <tr><td class=Forms>ICAO: </td><td><input type="text" value="" name="ICAO" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Name: </td><td><input type="text" value="Airbus A320" name="nombre" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Price: </td><td><input maxlength="9" value="1000000" type="text" name="precio" /> €</td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Number Classes: </td></td><td><select name="numberclasses" id="numberclasses" onchange="callAjax()">
        <option>Select Number of Classes</option>
        <?php
        echo'<option value="1">One</option>';
        ?>
    </select></td></tr>


<tr><td id="classes" ></td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Capacidad: </td><td><input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /> pasajeros</td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Insertar"/>
    </form>
    <?
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

classes.php

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['Value'];

if($value == 1){


    ?>


<thead>
    <td class=Forms>First Class: </td><td><input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /></td>
</thead>


<?php
}

?>
```

And the result is http://i50.tinypic.com/2yjzinr.png